# how to determine maximum length of chain of tail-to-head connections in a given word list

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

Given a finite set of words, I wish to to write an algorithm which will create a chain of words, where the tail (last letter) of a word `n` will be the same as the head (first letter) of word `n+1`. I assume there can be 0 to n! number of chains, and the length of such chains can be `0 to n`.

An algorithm to find the length of the longest chain for a given set of words of size `n` can be:

1. Create all chains (`n!` chains)
2. Check all chains and dispose illegal ones (those in which the tail of at least one word is not equal to the head of the subsequent word)
3. Determine length of remaining legal chains
4. Find maximum length

First 3 steps can be executed during a single run (i.e. create chain > check it > if legal, determine length), but that would still mean this algorithm will run `n!` times in worst case.

I wonder if there is a way to calculate the length of the longest chain for a given set of words, without having to check all possible chains in advance.

Comment: Well the maximum chain cannot be longer than the size of the set of words, an it *can* be as long (like for the set $\{ab,bc,cd,de\}$).

Comment: I have edited my question since it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I advise you to first present an algorithm you have, and then ask if there is any faster algorithm...

Comment: @5xum I have done as you advised.

Answer (score 0):

There certainly is a better way than what you did. For example, for $n=100$, your algorithm cannot be run on any computer smaller than our universe, since you cannot store all $n!$ chains anywhere in memory.

I advise you to improve your algorithm to only create legal chains, which will greatly decrease the work you have to do.